# Should gdal2 installation include CLI commands gdal_calc.py and gdal_merge?

Tags: gdal

I have gdal2 (v2.4) installed on my mac using homebrew.  When I try to run either `gdal_calc.py` or `gdal_merge` from the command line I get the error

`-bash: gdal_merge: command not found`

or
`-bash: gdal_calc.py: command not found`

Going to my the bin where homebrew installed gdal2 I can see that indeed neither `gdal_calc.py` nor `gdal_merge` is there.  These seem to be fairly fundamental commands, however, and other common commands such as `gdal_translate` are present.

[image: Commands present in my GDAL2 bin]

Should `gdal_merge` and `gdal_calc.py` have been present in that folder?  If not, where should they be or how do I install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are python scripts that add to GDAL, so you will need to install one of `python-gdal` or `python3-gdal` (at least that is the names on Ubuntu).

On a Mac - `brew install gdal2-python` You may also have to add the folder to your path using `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This worked with `brew install gdal2-python` on the mac.
I also had to add the folder to my path using
`echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile`